# About Memory Layout of application and the logical address of some variable

Tags: ios, linux, macos, memory

A little similar with [Memory Layout of application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676477/memory-layout-of-application).

An identical hardware, the same OS and the same compiler on it, can i be sure that memory layout **in the virtual memory space** of the application exactly be the same? Can i be sure, that the same variable's logical address is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

<sup>because of address space layout randomization</sup>